# Checking one value of a dataframe in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames as shown below:

df1:

```
OSIED    geometry
257005   POLYGON ((311852.712 178933.993, 312106.023 17...
017049   POLYGON ((272943.107 137755.159, 272647.627 13...
017032   POLYGON ((276637.425 146141.397, 276601.509 14.
```

df2:

```
small_area Median_BER
2570059001   212.9
017049002    212.9
217112003    212.9
```

I need to search for `df1.col1` in `df2.col2` using "contains" logic and if it matches, get all the columns from both dataframes:

```
 osied   geometry              small_area   ber
 257005  POLYGON ((311852.71   2570059001   212.9
```

I am new to python, which function which does this? `isin` function isn't useful here.

Comment: What do you mean by *"df1.col1 in df2.col2 using "contains" logic"*? How is 123 contained in 124? I don't see how it is "contained", whether we use string, integer or list operations

Comment: Do you need to return all columns only if all columns match, or only return those columns where there is a match across the dataframes?

Comment: What the comments above says, and where did `345` go?

Comment: Given your expected result, this appears to be just a concatenation: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`. Then rename the columns in the result.

Comment: I want to search col1 values from dataframe 1 in col1 values in dataframe 2. They wont match entirey hence I would like to use contains/like function in python. If it matches all values from both frames should be displayed

Comment: Can you create a most exhaustive test case?

Comment: Duplicate quaint did us for using SQL like commands, but I believe OP is looking for panda like commands. Also in comments for proposed answer, is a reason the proposed duplicate won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:
Try this:

```
if any(df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)):
     pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

---

*I think what you are probably looking for is some kind of merge. You can do:*

```
df2.merge(df1, left_on='col2', right_on='col1', how='inner')
```

*or change the 'how' argument based on what you're looking for.*

Comment: merge wont work because not all values match from df1.col1 with df2.col1..meaning to say there is no primary key

Comment: So are you looking for if any value in the specified columns match, and if so then return all columns from both dataframes?

Comment: Yes.....in sql we could use like operator...how would be go about that in python

Comment: @Tina see above. Basically this checks to see if there are any matches in the two specified columns, and if so then return a horizontal stack of the two dataframes.

Comment: it doenst work..not sure for what reason it doesnt get into the ifloop

Comment: I have modified the data to reflect the original dataset.. ifany doesnt work in thi scase

Comment: Ok, the updated post shows why that wouldn't work. I'm trying to think what would work beyond a nested loop, but I'm not aware of any built-in functions that would do what you want.

Comment: Maybe try looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41590139/12229158